# How to select more than one checkboxes based on passing values in Selenium WebDriver (Using Java)

Tags: java, selenium

Lets see the below scenario.
On the registration form, there is field called "Hobbies" which has three check boxes "Reading", "Dance" and "Cricket".

I have to select two check boxes "Reading" and "Cricket". I have to pass one string value (e.g. "Reading,Cricket") to one method say "selectMultipleCheckboxes". So, based on passing value, it should split the string and it should select two check boxes.

Note: I don't want to select single check box or all check boxes.

Could you please help me to write test script?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to solve the problem and provide the code snippet that doesn't work for you, then we will try to help. Thanks!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding service.  You have to show some effort.  How far have you got? Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really an expert on Java, but since someone just answered my question, I thought I would at least try to help you out.
You would do something like this:

```
String originalText = "Reading,Cricket";
String[] parts = originalText.split(",");
String readingPart = parts[0];
String cricketPart = parts[1];
```

Then you would pass those strings to Selenium:

```
driver.findElement(By.id(cricketPart)).click();
```

That would of course be assuming your checkbox's DOM ID was called "Cricket"